# Is it possible to set a preference with a MySQL 'OR' query?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table that contains nutritional data for vegetables (for example).  In some cases (but not all), the data may differ according to the variety of vegetable.

On a page-level, I want to output the data for the variety itself if it's present, but if not, then output the data for the vegetable in general.

Here's my query (the 'carrot' values are actually numeric in reality, I've changed them here for ease of understanding);

```
SELECT *
FROM fp_nutrition
WHERE fpID='carrot variety' AND approval_status='approved'
OR
fpID='carrot' AND approval_status='approved'
ORDER BY nutriID DESC
```

For clarity, let's assume this query is run on the page for 'carrot variety'.

In its current form, it returns (for example) 2 rows - one for 'carrot' and one for 'carrot variety'.  Is there a way I can change this query so it only returns a single row - BUT that single row is the most appropriate of (so 'carrot variety' being preferred, but 'carrot' returned if it's not there).

The only solution I have come up with so far is to order by fpID DESC and LIMIT 1, however that relies on the data for 'carrot' always being added first (likely, but I'd prefer not to have to rely on that scenario).

Comment: To solve this problem in a general way, each row in your result set needs some sort of metric of desirability. Then you `ORDER BY that_metric DESC LIMIT 1` and get the most desirable row. You thought of using `fpID` as the metric, but you know it's not reliable. You could use `LENGTH(something)` as the metric and get the row with the longest description.  At any rate you must work out the metric.

Comment: Plus, you need to group `AND` and `OR` operations with parentheses in your query to get the results you hope for.

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't have worked here because the 'names' are not actually in the table (as I mentioned, I used 'carrot' etc in my example just for ease of understanding) - the table itself is entirely numerical data.  @Kobi below has posted a simple solution that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `UNION` the result of the 2 query, but only display the second one if the first one doesn't exists

=> display 'carrot variety' and carrot(only if carrot variety does not exists)

```
 SELECT *
      FROM fp_nutrition
     WHERE fpID            = 'carrot variety'
       AND approval_status = 'approved'
    UNION
    SELECT *
      FROM fp_nutrition
     WHERE fpID            = 'carrot'
       AND approval_status = 'approved'
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                          FROM fp_nutrition
                         WHERE fpID            = 'carrot variety'
                           AND approval_status = 'approved' )
     ORDER BY nutriID DESC
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!